# Migrating C# to Python - Random class

Tags: c#, python, random

I need to migrate some C# code to Python. The original code makes use of the `Random` class. The migrated code must be cycle-accurate (namely consecutive calls to `Next()` must produce the same results in both codes). Some questions:

- Is there a call-equivalent to C#'s `Random` in Python?
- Alliteratively, assuming I can modify both sources, is there a pseudo-random library which works with both C# and Python?

Comment: Write your own PRNG for both languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any library that is available for both Python and C# and which generates the same random numbers for both. However, you may be able to take advantage of IronPython. The default `Random` implementation differs between IronPython and CPython, but the `WichmannHill` class does not.

You can use C# to instantiate the `WichmannHill` class in IronPython and get the same values as CPython for the same seed. Alternatively, you can implement the Wichmann-Hill algorithm in C# relatively easily by translating the Python code in `random.py`.

Another option is to take the [CPython implementation](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/_randommodule.c?revision=81029&view=markup) of `Random`'s Mersenne Twister algorithm and translate that to C# to get identical results.

Comment: I second the use of Mersenne Twister. It's a much better randomiser than the built-in Random() (for c# at least, I don't know about IronPython). Don't use it (or indeed Random()) for cryptography though.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I ended up needing a solution to this. I ended up implementing C#'s Random class in python. It works as long as you don't need random numbers larger than 2147483647, I ended up not needing that functionality so I left it unimplemented.

https://gist.github.com/BadStreff/541cf2e6953b3c666f83127a1d4f6a47

```
from ctypes import *
# implemented from:
# http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,dec894a7e816e665
class Random(object):
    def __init__(self, seed):
        self.seed = c_int(seed).value
        self.MBIG = 2147483647
        self.MMIN = -2147483648
        self.MZ = 0
        self.MSEED = 161803398
        self.SeedArray = [0] * 56

        if seed == self.MMIN:
            subtraction = self.MBIG
        else:
            subtraction = abs(seed)

        mj = c_int(self.MSEED - subtraction).value
        self.SeedArray[55] = mj
        mk = 1
        for i in range(1, 55):
            ii = (21 * i) % 55
            self.SeedArray[ii] = mk
            mk = mj - mk
            if mk < 0:
                mk += self.MBIG
            mj = self.SeedArray[ii]
        for k in range(1, 5):
            for i in range(1, 56):
                self.SeedArray[i] -= self.SeedArray[1 + (i + 30) % 55]
                if self.SeedArray[i] < 0:
                    self.SeedArray[i] = c_int(self.SeedArray[i] + self.MBIG).value
        self.inext = 0
        self.inextp = 21
        self.seed = 1

    def InternalSample(self):
        locINext = self.inext + 1
        locINextp = self.inextp + 1

        if locINext >= 56:
            locINext = 1
        if locINextp >= 56:
            locINextp = 1

        retVal = c_int(self.SeedArray[locINext] - self.SeedArray[locINextp]).value
        if retVal == self.MBIG:
            retVal -= 1
        if retVal < 0:
            retVal = c_int(retVal + self.MBIG).value
        self.SeedArray[locINext] = retVal
        self.inext = locINext
        self.inextp = locINextp
        return retVal

    def Next(self, minValue=None, maxValue=None):
        if minValue == None:
            return self.InternalSample()
        valRange = maxValue - minValue
        if valRange <= self.MBIG:
            return int(c_float(self.Sample() * valRange).value) + minValue
        else:
            return self.GetSampleForLargeRange() * valRange + minValue

    def GetSampleRangeForLargeRange(self):
        pass

    def Sample(self):
        s = self.InternalSample()
        ret = c_double(s * c_double(1.0/self.MBIG).value).value
        # print(f'sample: {s}\nret: {ret}')
        return ret
```

Comment: Post your implementation here, in case the gist gets deleted or the link goes down.